# Online and automatic resource localization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I have a c# winforms project with many forms, now I want to localize these forms to another language, is there any way or code that generates resource files for forms and translate them online?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are open source tools which allow to translate resx files. I haven't found a version which uses a online translation service such as [google translate](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/language/translate/overview.html) or the [microsoft translator api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576286.aspx) or even the bablefish. But I think the [Resx Translation Helper](http://resx.codeplex.com/) (open source project) should be very easy to modify. Note however, that the author explicitly discourage the usage of autogenerated translation:

> It does NOT automatically translate because user-translation is currently still much better than automated translation.

Comment: This blog post solves my problem : http://www.codecapers.com/post/An-Automatic-Resource-File-Translation-Tool.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you will be able to generate resx file from your sources. maybe Crowdin.net will be suitable solution for online translations.

Answer (score 1):

The [Visual Localizer](https://visuallocalizer.codeplex.com) tool utilizes Google Translate, Microsoft Translator and MyMemory for this very purpose. It has also many other features regarding automatic localization in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReSharper plugin and/or  [RGreatEx - The ReSharper Great Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/DTReSharperPlugin.aspx)
  and U can easily Move strings to resource to translate them for specific language.